# Something wrong with the Euler Lagrange equation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

**The Question:**

Find an extremal corresponding to $$\int_{-1}^1ydx$$ subject to the conditions $$y(-1)=y(1)=0\qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_{-1}^1(y^2+y'^2)dx=1$$

---

**My Attempt:**

Not much of an attempt here, but the point is I keep running into contradictions.

By the Euler-Lagrange equation, the extremal satisfies

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$

where in this case $F(x,y,y')=y$. Plugging it in, we get $-1=0$???

Similarly, Beltrami's Identity states that if $F$ is not explicitly dependent on $x$, then

$$\frac{d}{dx}\biggl[ y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-F \biggr ] =0$$

which implies that $y=\text{constant}$.

The conditions $y(-1)=y(1)=0$ imply that $y(x) \equiv 0$, but then this wouldn't satisfy the other condition...

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Your $F$ is wrong because you have not incorporated the constraint.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it means or how to incorporate the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a constrained variational problem. The correct Lagrangian should be
$$
F(x,y,y')=y-\lambda\left(y^2+y'^2\right),
$$
where $\lambda$ a Lagrange multiplier (a constant) to be determined.

Apply Euler-Lagrange equation to the above Lagrangian, and
$$
1-2\lambda y=-2\lambda y'',
$$
whose solution, together with the imposed boundary condition $y(-1)=y(1)=0$, reads
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\frac{1+e^2-2e\cosh x}{1+e^2}.
$$
Finally, $\lambda$ shall be determined by using the constraint
$$
\int_{-1}^1\left(y^2+y'^2\right){\rm d}x=1,
$$
which yields
$$
\lambda=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^2}}.
$$

To sum up, the very function $y$ you are expecting should be
$$
y(x)=\pm\frac{1+e^2-2e\cosh x}{2\sqrt{1+e^2}}.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\lambda^2=\dfrac{1}{1+e^2}$?

Comment: But anyway, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @glowstonetrees: Thank you very much for correcting me. I must have made some fatal mistakes. I just updated my post. Thank you :-)

Comment: @glowstonetrees: One more comment here. As per the correct solution, you will get the minimum of your functional $\int_{-1}^1y(x){\rm d}x$ if you take "$-$", whereas you will get the maximum of it if you take "$+$".